# Setting a session and ajax call happens parallely

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, session

I am setting a session variable in doGet() like

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("MySessionVariable", "String goes here");
```

I am trying to display that in my JSP page upon ready like

```
<%= session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable")%>
```

and I am making a call to the servlet on ready like

```
<Script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "UserInfoDisplay"
            });
        });
</Script>
```

But what I see is that, the value is null for the first time and when I refresh again I get the value. That is the ajax call onReady and the page load happens parallely. How should I fix this? I want the data to appear on the first load itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exactly like that. Page load happens first, and when the page is loaded, it invokes the servlet. You have to take into account that `<%= session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable")%>` is executed server side, before the browser gets any HTML. Then, the browser gets the response and your script calls the server again and sets the property, but the page was already rendered. You have to do this in a different way. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to load a list from Servlet in drop down when my page loads for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only for the first time, then why make a ajax call in the first place?
Ajax is meant for sending asynchronous requests. Correct me if I am wrong, the better approach would be to redirect a request to the servlet and get a response, isnt it?